# PHP MySQL PDO Query always Returns 1

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb

I am trying to get a particular value from the database, however, it always returns 1 as the result instead of the expected result.

I am new to PHP and PDO.

Here is the query

```
$query = " 
            SELECT 
                email,
                userlevel
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        ";
```

Here are the parameter values I pass

```
$query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_SESSION['user']["username"] 
        );
```

Then I run

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
$result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

And when I try to display the result with the code, it always returns 1

```
<?php echo print_r(array_values($row)); ?>
```

The expected result should be something like

```
Array
(
        (
            [email] => testuser@testh2.com
            [userlevel] => 5
        )

)
```

I have been searching for hours and I just can't seem to find the issue.
I have verified that the username parameter is passed correctly.

Comment: What happens when you do `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` ?

Comment: `echo print_r` is a mess. `Echo` does the same as `print_r`, and as `print_r` returns `1` (or probably `true`) so you see it `echo`'ed

Comment: debugging: `var_dump( $_SESSION['user']["username"], $result, $row);` - immediately after the `$row = $stmt->fetch();` statement.  Displays wot?  Anything you recognize as useful?

Comment: change `$result = $stmt->execute(query_params);` to `$stmt->execute(query_params);`

Comment: drat, you don't have error display E_ALL on. `$query_params` not `query_params` - is a constant ;-/

Comment: Parziphal, Nothing? I am not sure where to check that.

u_mulder, When I use echo $row it does nothing.

@RyanVincent string(5) "test" bool(true) array(2) { ["email"]=> string(23) "testuser@testh2.co" ["userlevel"]=> string(1) "5" } So I see it! How do I access it :(

drat, I am sorry, that was a typo that was not there in the code. I have edited it.

Comment: @RyanVincent So I removed the rest of the variables from the dump. 
`var_dump($row)` and that gave `array(2) { ["email"]=> string(23) "testuser@testh2.com" ["userlevel"]=> string(1) "5" }`

Comment: The var_dump was the clue...  `$row` is the array and `$row['email']` and `$row['userlevel']` is what you expect. i.e. `echo $row['email'];` will output the email address. A similar expression of the userlevel will work.

Comment: Ah. When I do `$row["userlevel"]` it works!! Thank you @RyanVincent

I was trying `$row[0]["userlevel"]`...I guess that was not needed.

Comment: Was fun assisting. :) Please write an answer about your experience. You can now use `var_dump` to find out if things are what you expect. enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

As [@RyanVincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3184785/ryan-vincent) pointed out using `var_dump()` allowed me to see what the values in $row were. As it was an array it had to be read as `$row["userlevel"]`

Running `var_dump($row)` gave `array(2) { ["email"]=> string(23) "testuser@testh2.com" ["userlevel"]=> string(1) "5" }` as the result.

Thanks to [@RyanVincent](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3184785/ryan-vincent) and everyone else who helped!

Comment: @RyanVincent I posted it, but I am wondering why  `<?php echo print_r(array_values($row)); ?>` did not work.

Comment: Break it down? `var_dump($row, array_values($row));`. Remember, you can store anything in PHP. So, `$arrayValuesRow = array_values($row);` So, display: `var_dump($arrayValuesRow);`. And - `print_r($arrayValuesRow);`. They should work. You may need to wrap the 'print_r' in HTML '<pre>...</pre>' tags.